# Parent Entity referenced in Docs but I can't find how to actually set it up and Packages are not documented

Tags: slingr

The Developer documentation makes reference to Parent Entity when creating an entity. Has this feature been deprecated?

Also, the what are Packages in Slingr? There's no reference to it in the user documentation either.

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Parent Entity` is a feature that is still in beta for some apps, it is not publicly available. This is used for inheritance.

Packages allow to organize your entities. This is helpful when your app starts to grow and you have many entities. Think them as packages in Java, which are used to organize your classes.